# Floating point arithmetic in Javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I have just started playing around with Javascript in the last couple of days and I have noticed something that appears to be quite peculiar. When I add some numbers together, I end up with a marginally incorrect answer.

`4.99 + 0.98 = 5.970000000000001`

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I invite you to read "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)".

Comment: It's a lot to know... it should be called "What A Computer Scientist **Could** Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf` like this:

```
console.log(sprintf("%.2f", (4.99 + 0.98))); // 5.97
```